# Is it possible to limit user connection IP range with SQL instead of editing pg_hba.conf?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-rds

We are using AWS PostgreSQL RDS and we would like to limit some accounts to be accessed from a specific set of CIDR. Since RDS is managed DBMS by AWS we do not have access to pg_hba.conf.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html

By checking the CREATE ROLE and USER DDL in PG, it does not seem to be an option.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try to write you own rules via function/procedure checking, using `SELECT inet_server_addr()` (just keep in mind that it works only with non-localhost connections).

Also some useful functions here (like local/remote ip/port): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-info.html